# How are mysqli_connect Arguments optional?

Tags: php, mysqli

According to the PHP manual, all the arguments of the [`mysqli_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) function are optional:

```
mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname,$port,$socket);
```

What does it mean to be 'Optional'? What don't I understand is how can we skip any of those values and let it use the default values?

Comment: Not sure whether you checked the [official docs](http://php.net/mysqli_connect). The method signature shown there includes the default values (e.g. `string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")`).

Comment: Thanks Álvaro for the link, but one thing still remains unclear, what default database gets selected if I pass in an empty string `(" ")` for database part in `mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname,$port,$socket);` ?

Comment: Whatever is set in the `mysqli.default_host` INI directive; that's what the `ini_get("mysqli.default_host")` documentation syntax means. If that's empty too, it connects to `localhost` (that's probably hard-coded in the PHP source code written in C).

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me Álvaro and I perfectly got that. My doubt lies on the 4th argument which takes in the database name. Suppose I write it like this:
`mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,"",$port,$sock‌​et);` with an empty string for database name,which database gets selected? is there any default database just as there is a default user account 'root' ?

Comment: That appears to be a slighly different question. It won't select any. In SQL it isn't mandatory to select a working database; you'll just need to add the database name to all your queries: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop.customers`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify default MySQL credentials straight in the php.ini configuration file.

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.default-port as a reference.

Then, if you call mysqli_connect(), the connection still will be made using those settings from php.ini (assuming they are correct of course).

Unless what you don't understand is the idea of default arguments? Sorry if I am wrong but I couldn't clearly figure it out from your question. If that is the case please: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: Thanks matiit for the reply, but one thing still remains unclear, what default database gets selected if I pass in an empty string (" ") for dbName part in mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname,$port,$sock‌​et); ?

Answer (score 1):

When arguments are optional it means that you do not need to provide any value. The function will work as usual with any number of arguments.

`new mysqli()`/`mysqli_connect()` has default values for all arguments. These values can be specified in the INI file. When connecting PHP will use the default values if none were provided in the function call.

If you want to skip one of the arguments in the middle you can pass `NULL` or an empty string which will also tell mysqli to use the default value.

**Careful**. The PHP manual says that `mysqli_connect()` and `new mysqli` are aliases of each other but that is not entirely true. If you don't provide any arguments to `mysqli_connect()` it will pick the default one. However, `new mysqli()` will not attempt connecting at all. It will behave exactly like `mysqli_init()` if no arguments are provided. You can overcome this problem in two ways:

```
// pass null as a single argument
$mysqli = new mysqli(null);

// call connect manually
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it myself. This was totally a noob one. Since `mysqli_connect` takes in different strings as its arguments, 'Optional' (and hence skipping an argument) means providing empty string `("")`as argument, in which case it uses the default values.

Comment: Optional means that you can skip it entirely. `<?php mysqli_connect();` is a valid PHP script.